# .NET: Is "foreach" command?

Tags: .net, syntax, command

I have just a terminology question. I have read that if, foreach etc. are **statements** but what does it mean in the terminology - are these commands? 
It is maybe "lost in the translation" problem

Answer (score 3):

From [Statement (programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_%28programming%29)

> In computer programming a statement can be thought of as the smallest standalone element of an imperative programming language. A program is formed by a sequence of one or more statements. A statement will have internal components (e.g., expressions).
>
> Many languages (e.g. C) make a distinction between statements and definitions, with a statement only containing executable code and a definition declaring an identifier. A distinction can also be made between simple and compound statements; the latter may contain statements as components.

In a nutshell it is one of many instructions in the language that makes the program to perform some very basic action. Through combining statements you define a complex activity that makes sense to you as an author. You define it by using little building blocks namely those statements.

Comment: Thanks, also they are statements, so they are "commands" as they are executable

Answer (score 2):

A command and a statement is generally the same thing.

However, when talking about commands, it's usually something that a user enters directly rather than a statement in a program.

Also, while a command generally is an instruction to do something, a statement can also be instructions that doesn't actually perform anything, like for example declaring a constant value:

```
const int Answer = 42;
```

Comment: That is not a statement, it is a declaration  :)

Comment: @leppie: Good point. Let's use a declaration that is a statement as example instead. :)

Comment: That is still primarily a declaration, the fact that the compiler 'magically' store and initialize the value is kinda irrelevant.

Comment: @leppie: So any expression that ends with a semicolon is a statement, *except* if it happens to declare something also? Or is it just when I write something that it isn't a statement? ;)

Comment: Declarations end with a `;` too, but i'm getting tired. Go read the C# grammar, you might be surprised :)

Answer (score 0):

A statement is an expression that has no return value (or void or unspecified).

Comment: Do you have any references for this?

Comment: Many statements actually have a return value, like `x = 42` for example.

Comment: @Guffa: If you terminate any expression with a `;`, it becomes a statement.

Comment: @Stefan Steinegger: You can find this in the C# spec, grammar section. Pretty much goes for any 'procedural' language.  (procedural is not quite correct, but I cant think of an easier description)